# Wolfram: doing substitution on indexed terms

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I have

```
sx = Sum[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, 10}]^2 // Expand
```

It expands in sum of 55 terms, from which

1. $x_i^2$ - 10 terms, actual representation: $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+...$
2. $2 \cdot x_i \cdot x_{i+1}$ - 9 terms, actual representation: $2 x_1 x_2 + 2 x_2 x_3 + ...$
3. $2 \cdot x_i \cdot x_{i+l}, l>1$ - all the rest, actual representation: $2 x_1 x_3 + 2 x_2 x_4 + ...$

For my calculations I need to replace terms

1. => $p \cdot (1-p)$
2. => 0
3. => $2 \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^2$

I tried to perform straight-forward

sx1 = sx /. $\{x_1^2 -> 1\}$

but nothing happened at all.

What I would like to achieve: some small easy to maintain rule formula to perform such substitutions. I saw Wolfram Mathematica is very difficult with values with subscripts. Is it possible, or should I look for some another alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong, $sx/.\{x_1^2 \to 1\}$ does substitutes $x_1^2$ with $1$.

Comment: @Moo: Please, let me know how to re-target this question to that Universe. I did not want to violate any rules, it is just be chance...

Comment: You can use the "flag" link (on bottom of question) and ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: @jjagmath: of course I can attach an image of my Mathematica window, but it just happens. Maybe I am missing some important setting, or flag somewhere in settings? I have a Student Edition version, is it possible it is somehow limited in functionality?

Comment: That functionality is in every version of Mathematica. And you'll need to mess very badly with the settings to break that. Can you copy and paste the lines you're writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I found a solution for my own problem.

- Replacing all square terms with p*(1-p):

```
sx = sx /. Table[Subscript[x, i]^2 -> p*(1 - p), {i, 1, 10}]
```

- Replacing $x_i \cdot x_{i+1}$ terms with $0$:

```
sx = sx /. Table[Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[x, i + 1] -> 0, {i, 1, 9}]
```

- Replacing $x_i \cdot x_{i+l}, l>1$ terms with $p^2 \cdot (1-p)^2$

```
sx = sx /. Table[Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[x, i + 2] -> p^2*(1-p)^2, {i, 1, 8}]
```

Unfortunately, last statement must be edited and repeated many times to correct second subscript index. Let's say, provided example is replacing terms like $x_1 \cdot x_3, \text{... } x_8 \cdot x_{10}$ with $p^2 \cdot (1-p)^2$, while to replace other term patterns a bit different expressions are necessary. I tried to use double-indexing in Table[] function, but it creates 2D array, which is not doing what is intended.

I would like to express my appreciation to all auditory of this problem, without your help I would not get to the solution. I think this solution could be made more elegant, but I do not have yet necessary knowledge to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry, I spotted the problem. You don't want Indexed[x,i], you should write Subscript[x,i]

Comment: Yes, it does provide an answer. If ```Indexed``` is changed to ```Subscript``` the code will do what the author is expecting.

Comment: Yes, it provides an asnwer. Don't worry @jjagmath, more of "high rep guys" has the work of review answers and they just copy paste that text from above just to get more "popularity"

Comment: @jjagmath, after changing Indexed to Subscript it started to work, but only for term, which I specify explicitly. Is it possible to specify a formula for which I need substitution? For example, in case of square terms, I need to substitute all square terms according to logic I described in my OP. Is it possible to replace _all_ square terms without mentioning them explicitly on the line with some command?